# How to add pairs of key, value to jQuery array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I have a group of checkboxes and I want to add their values which contains a pair of numbers to an array, then use them. The problem is array takes only value of last checkbox. I struggled a lot but couldn't figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/zfwbtomu/

HTML:

```
<div class="scrolly-option" id="input-option20">
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[20][]" value="20,64">
            <span>Mint</span> </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[20][]" value="20,63">
            <span>Maroon</span> </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[20][]" value="20,62">
            <span>Ecru</span> </label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="option1" name="" value="" />
<div class="result"></div>
<button type="button" class="button-cart">ADD</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.button-cart').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  var firstoptoins = [];
  $(".scrolly-option input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      var arr = $(this).val().split(',');
      firstoptoins[arr[0]] = arr[1];
    }
  });

  console.log(firstoptoins);

  $('.scrolly-option .checkbox input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);

  $.each(firstoptoins, function (o, v) {
    $('.option1').attr("name", 'option[' + o + '][]');
    $('.option1').attr("value", v);
    $('.option1').prop('checked', true);
    console.log('o: ' + o + ' v: ' + v);
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you want your array to format? You are using `20` as index to all of the element on the array and that is the reason why you are only getting the last value.

Comment: OMG! You're right!

Comment: yeah @Eddie  is right there you are using the first `value` as `index` for the `firstoptions` array so all values will be copied to same index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the first number as an index which is `20` that is the reason why you are only getting one element on your array.

It element `firstoptoins[20]` is getting replaced on each and every loop.

You can do something like:

```
var firstoptoins = [];

$(".scrolly-option input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            var arr = $(this).val().split(',');
            firstoptoins.push( [ arr[0], arr[1] ] );
        }
});

console.log(firstoptoins);
```

this will result to:

```
[ 
    [ "20", "64" ],
    [ "20", "63" ],
    [ "20", "62" ] 
]
```

---

The second loop will be:

```
$.each(firstoptoins, function (o, v) {
    $('.option1').attr("name", 'option[' + v[0] + '][]');
    $('.option1').attr("value", v[1]);
    $('.option1').prop('checked', true);
    console.log('o: ' + v[0] + ' v: ' + v[1]);
});
```

Use `v[0]` for the first number and `v[1]` for the second number

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'd appreciate if you also tell me how to iterate between array items. The output of array is like this: (3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0
:
(2) ["54", "175"]
1
:
(2) ["54", "174"]
2
:
(2) ["54", "173"]

Comment: @Kardo The example you gave is not the same value on your input checkbox, the values are `20,64`,`20,63` and `20,62` ,

Comment: Im not sure but I think, my example above has the same format with `0 : (2) ["54", "175"] 1 : (2) ["54", "174"] 2 : (2) ["54", "173"]`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying another product: (3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0
:
(2) ["20", "64"]
1
:
(2) ["20", "63"]
2
:
(2) ["20", "62"]

Comment: I think you will achieve that format with my example above. @Kardo

Comment: Yes, right, now array is OK, but my previous iteration method doesn't work anymore: $.each(firstoptoins, function (o, v) { $('.option1').attr("name", 'option[' + o + '][]'); ...

Comment: I added the second loop on my answer @Kardo. Please check.

Comment: Thanks a million! You saved me!

Comment: Happy to help @Kardo